# ion-text color - is it a bug it only accepts literals?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I was looking here under [Ionic Typeography](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/typography/Typography/)

I can't seem to get it to work for anything other than a literal.

So **html**

```
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let name of names"
                ion-text color="getSassColor(name)" 
                (click)="select(name)">
        {{name.name}}
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**ts**

```
  private names = [
    { name : 'John',   selected:false},
    { name : 'Paul',   selected:false},
    { name : 'George', selected:false},
    { name : 'Ringo',  selected:false}
  ];
  ...
  select(selectedName) {
    this.names.forEach((n) => {
      if (n.name === selectedName.name) {
        n.selected = !n.selected;
      }
    });
  }
  getSassColor(name): string {
    console.log('in get sass')
    return name.selected ? 'primary' : '';
  }
```

doesn't ever call **getSassColor()**, if you want to condition colour.

The log message 'in get sass' never displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` to bind to property, like `[propertyName] == bind-property-name`

To your example, you can bind the `color` property

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item ion-text *ngFor="let name of names" (click)="select(name)"
       [color]="getSassColor(name)" >
       {{name.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily like below.I have tested below code and it is working fine.

***Important Note:***

1: You must never use `private` properties inside the `.ts` file if you use those on the `template` file (i.e. `html`).Otherwise, `AOT` compiler will fail.

2: When you use the `ion-text` you need to give an `element` to it.Since you need to use it with your `name` property you need to use `div` like `element` or else with it.

*.scss*

```
 .my-class {
     color: color($colors, primary);
 }
```

*.html*

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let name of names" (click)="select(name)">
      <div ion-text [ngClass]="{'my-class': name.selected }">{{name.name}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```